# Missing libraries in CppUnit 1.12.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, cppunit

I need to learn how to use and manipulate the old version of Cpp Unit 1.12.1 for a client that uses it. However, when I tried to obtain a copy from SourceForge, it appears that [the CPPUnit 1.12.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/files/cppunit/1.12.1/) version does not contain library files. There are no library files inside the lib folder! I think there's supposed to be because I'm using CppUnit with Visual Studio 2010 and all the necessary syntax is unidentifiable.

Also I was wondering how would I connect Cpp Unit 1.12.1 with Visual Studio 2010. That is, how do I add it as a reference or import the library so that Visual Studio detects that I'm using it?

Trying to do all this on windows.

EDIT: When I try building cppunit solution under debug, I receive an [error similar to this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97f50350-e37a-46ba-a921-8f4afa29db03/error-msb3073-exited-with-code-3?forum=vcgeneral). I tried setting my outdir to the same command provided in that post but it doesn't help. However, it might have something to do with converting VS 6 files to VS 10.

However, I also get these warnings:

```
Warning 1   warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\~\Downloads\cppunit-1.12.1.tar\cppunit-1.12.1\cppunit-1.12.1\src\cppunit\.\Debug\cppunit.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\~\Downloads\cppunit-1.12.1.tar\cppunit-1.12.1\cppunit-1.12.1\src\cppunit\Debug\cppunitd.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1151    6   cppunit

Warning 2   warning MSB8012: TargetName(cppunit) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (cppunitd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1153    6   cppunit
```

Comment: I think you have to build them yourself.  There's a CppUnitLibraries.dsw (Visual Studio 6 workspace) in the src folder.  VS2010 should open and upgrade that for you, then you can add the resultant project file to your exising solution.  There's no guarantee the code will compile, though, as there have been a fair few changes to VS since then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a Visual Studio 2010 buildable version [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3215/tools/cppunitAll.html) along with some example usage and instructions.

Hope this helps, however let me know if you need more info and I will dig some up:)

**Addendum:**

I was unable to replicate Error MSB3073, and the solution worked fine to build all the projects.

I have uploaded a compiled set of files from the CPP Unit 1.12.1 project at [my site](http://dark-arts.tk/CPPUnit1.12.1_Files/CPPUnit1.12.1_Compiled.zip) in case you need them urgently.  Below are some instructions which should hopefully fix the problem.

Most commonly MSB3073 is related to post-build events, so you could either:

- Right click on your project-name in Visual Studio Solution Explorer:
- Properties >> Post-Build Event
- Remove the text from CommandLine textbox if you don't want post-build events. Or fix the path

Whis should fix it, or try and match the properties I have set (bear in mind you may habve to set these for release and debug as well as for x86 and x64, depending on what variant(s) are giving you the problem).

**For reference**

I have included my settings here as they are at the default setting for CPP Unit:

**CPP Unit project**
[image: CPP Unit]

**CPP Unit DLL project**
[image: CPP Unit DLL]

**DLL PlugIn Tester**
[image: DLL PlugIn Tester]

**Test PlugIn Runner**
[image: Test PlugIn Runner]

Test Runner
[image: Test Runner]

**To Utilise the DLL or lib file created:**

simply add the directory where the dll and lib reside to the additional library paramater shown here:
[image: Additional Lib]
After that all you need to do to enable the functionality within the dll or lib is #include the header and that should be you good to go.

Hopefully this will fix your problem, if not let me know:)

Comment: Ah I see. However, when I build Cppunit project from CppUnitlibraries, I get this build error:Error 3 error MSB3073: The command "copy "C:\Users\~\Downloads\cppunit-1.12.1.tar\cppunit-1.12.1\cppunit-1.12.1\src\cppunit\.\Debug\cppunit.lib" ..\..\lib\cppunit.lib
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113 6 cppunit

Comment: Thanks for your help! While the Post-Build event still didn't help, the link to the CppUnit1.12.1-VS2010 was worth it. I was able to build the library with no errors. However, now if you don't mind, I'm not sure how to link CppUnit to my VS2010 project. Where do I add the library? I tried to add the include file directory to C/C++ >additional include directories and the libraries under Linker > Input > Additional dependencies. However, my project still doesn't pick up the library.

Comment: Hi, I have added a section on utilising the dll/lib as well:)

Comment: My pleasure, you're welcome:)  Let me know if you need a hand again:)